# Why don't we call the function instead of returning it when writing a decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

I am learning decorators in Python and came across a problem. I don't quite understand why instead of providing arguments in the decorator and returning the function with the arguments(as in `@notaProperDecorator`) we just return the object of the functions inside (`@aProperDecorator`).

```py
def aProperDecorator(arg):
   print(arg)
   def outer(func):
      print("in outer")
      def inner(*args,**kwargs):
         print("in inner")
         return func(*args,**kwargs)
      return inner
   return outer

def functionToDecorate(*args,**kwargs):
   print("function")

def notaProperDecorator(arg):
   print(arg)
   def outer(func):
      print("in outer")
      def inner(*args,**kwargs):
         print("in inner")
         return func(*args,**kwargs)
      return inner(*args,**kwargs) #here
   return outer(func) #and here also
```

In this case, I thought something similar to Java would happen. That is, if a function returns a fuction we should directly call it (for example, `return function("test")`)
**EDIT:** As mentioned below, in my case the function outer is a proper decorator. I just wanted to use the complex case where both the decorator and the function can accept arguments.

Comment: `aProperDecorator` is not a decorator, it's a function that returns a decorator. `outer` is the decorator, `inner` is the object that will *replace* the decorated function. Perhaps that's the confusion?

Comment: Check what you return. In case of normal decorator, you return a *function*, in case of your test, you return a *function's result*. Also, check scopes - you don't have `func` yet, so you can't even do `outer(func)`. ;)

Comment: @h4z3. Could also be a class.

Comment: A function (`outer`) is not the same thing as a function call (`outer(func)`).

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you. I don't deal much with decorators myself, so I put what I know. :) (That's why it's only a comment, obviously.)

Comment: You can't call `outer` until you have an argument to pass to it. The point of returning `outer` is that someone else is going to call it later and provide that argument. I think you need to read some more about using functions as first-class values.

Comment: Why would the decorator *call* the decorated function? That would defeat the purpose of decorators. Decorators are supposed to *change* the decorated function, not *call* it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write something like this:

```
@decorator(arg)
def defined_function():
    do_something()
```

Python first calls `decorator(arg)`. The function `decorator` should return another function (`outer` in your case). (Note that functions and classes are objects in Python, so it is possible to return them from functions. Also note that `decorator` is not a decorator, the actual decorator is `outer`.) Python calls the returned decorator with `defined_function` as an argument. The decorator should then do something with `defined_function` and return a new function - or something else, as @MadPhysicist said (`inner` in your case). Python will then replace `defined_function` with the new function.

Comment: Technically, the decorator doesn't have to return an object of the same type that it was given. You can replace a function with a string using a decorator. Other code might not be happy with it, but you can do it just fine.

Comment: This is a good answer, but while it explains what does happen, it doesn't quite explain why we don't call the functions.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, but unfortunately I don't know any other way to explain why we don't call the functions other that "explaining what does happen".